# mod_rewrite for adding trailing slashes to symfony projects

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony-1.4

Currently, all the urls in my `routing.yml` are set up as

```
fooRoute:
url: /foo/
params: { module:foo, action: index}
```

Currently, users can access the foo/index action by going to `example.com/foo/`.  I would like to add a rewrite rule to so `example.com/foo` points to the same page.

The rewrite rule I have currently:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The regex that you are using, `^(.*)/$` matches requests that *end* with a slash, so `example.com/foo` will not match it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere "project-in-house" sollution of "trailing slashes" in symfony 1.4:

```
// project_root/lib/routing/MyProjectNamePatternRouting.class.php:
/**
 * fixes URL trailing slashes
 */
class MyProjectNamePatternRouting extends sfPatternRouting
{
    /**
     * @see sfPatternRouting
     */
    public function parse($url) {
        $url = rtrim($url, '/'); # trim trailing slashes before actual routing
        return parent::parse($url);
    }
}


// apps/frontend/config/factories.yml:
all:
...
  routing:
    class: MyProjectNamePatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
...
```